# Add success and error part

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically I got a response from a service. I am using AJAX calls to ASP.NET MVC action methods using jQuery. The method is at [here.](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/)
The result is shown in the place of id=Response1

```
function myFunction() {
         var strSearch = $('.txt1').val();
         var url = '@Url.Action("GetPassage", "Home")';
         $.get(url, { 'strSearch': strSearch }, function (data) {
             $('#Response1').css({"border-top-style": "groove","border-top-width": "4px","border-top-color": "#FF00FF","border-bottom-style": "groove","border-bottom-color": "#FF00FF","border-bottom-width": "4px"}).html(data);
         })
     }
```

What I want is if success let the above code works. If error, remove the border by changing the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `error` callback

```
$.get(url, {
    'strSearch': strSearch
}, function (data) {
    $('#Response1').css({
        "border-top-style": "groove",
        "border-top-width": "4px",
        "border-top-color": "#FF00FF",
        "border-bottom-style": "groove",
        "border-bottom-color": "#FF00FF",
        "border-bottom-width": "4px"
    }).html(data);
}).error(function () {
    // remove border
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/error/

Edit : as of your comment below, you are actually getting Error string in response and not an ajax error, in that case you can do this -

```
$.get(url, {
    'strSearch': strSearch
}, function (data) {
    if (data.indexOf('ERROR') < 0) {
        $('#Response1').css({
            "border-top-style": "groove",
                "border-top-width": "4px",
                "border-top-color": "#FF00FF",
                "border-bottom-style": "groove",
                "border-bottom-color": "#FF00FF",
                "border-bottom-width": "4px"
        }).html(data);
    } else {
        // remove border
    }
})
```

Comment: Test for error: I used error(function () {
                 $('#Response1').css({
                     "border-top-width": "0px",
                     "border-bottom-width": "0px"
                 }).html(data); but the borders are still there.

Comment: @Love  that means, you are not getting any error, anyway - what kind of error do you expect ?

Comment: If an error occurred, the result is ERROR: No query to look up.

Comment: @Love You mean  --  if `data === 'ERROR'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [statusCode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) options

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert("page not found");
    },
    200: function () {
        //do smth
    }
  }
});
```